# Transform a code in R to make it more efficient

Tags: r

I have to following code:

```
   WBP2=lapply(1:2500,function(j){as.data.frame(lapply(1:10000,function(i)
   {rowSums(data.frame((mapply(`*`,Theta[[j]],t(W[i,]),SIMPLIFY=FALSE))))}))})
```

W is a matrix 80 columns and 10000 rows, Theta is a list of 2500 matrices of 1000 rows and 80 columns. Our aim is to create 10000 dataframes for each 2500 simulations. Each data.frame would be the result of one row of W (W[i,]) multiplied by all the row of theta[[j]] ( thus a portfolio of 80 columns and 1000 rows). we just need the sum of each row of this portfolio therefore a data.frame of one column and 1000 rows)

here is a reproducible code

```
W=matrix((1:80), nrow =10, ncol=4)

theta= lapply(1:5,function(j){matrix((41:60),nrow=5,ncol=4)})

WBP=lapply(1:5,function(j){as.data.frame(lapply(1:10,function(i)  
{rowSums(data.frame(as.matrix(theta[[j]])%*%as.numeric(t(W[i,]))))}))})

View(WBP[[1]])
```

As you can see, it's quite heavy and my computer is not able to realize such thing.

Is there a way i could make it more efficient and less time consuming?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Explain by words what your code do

Comment: Looks like some linear algebra multiplication. What is the mathematical equivalent?

Comment: What is the use of `t(W[i,])` because it is a matrix of dimensions 1, 80 and even after transposing it, result with same dimensions will be generated?

Comment: I am guessing theta' * W?

Comment: I edited the post and hope it's clearer now. Thank you for your answers already

Comment: I think you would need to provide, a reproducible  example on how you generated the matrix (minimized version). For example something like your desired data cut down to W as 4 columns 10 rows, Theta as 10 matrices of 5 rows , and then what result you are expecting. This was, everyone can run a their solutions on the data and you can do Microbenchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one lapply

like :

```
wbp1=function()lapply(1:5,function(j){as.data.frame(as.matrix(theta[[j]])%*%as.matrix(t(W)))})
```

or using `tcrossprod`

```
wbp2=function()lapply(1:5,function(j){as.data.frame(tcrossprod(as.matrix(theta[[1]]),as.matrix(W)))})
```

## benchamrk

your variant

```
WBP=function()lapply(1:5,function(j){as.data.frame(lapply(1:10,function(i)  
    {rowSums(data.frame(as.matrix(theta[[j]])%*%as.numeric(t(W[i,]))))}))})




 microbenchmark(WBP(),wbp1(),wbp2())

 Unit: microseconds
   expr       min         lq       mean    median        uq       max neval cld
  WBP() 21965.723 22239.5595 24013.0301 22598.766 23971.683 80285.027   100   b
 wbp1()   613.607   623.5590   672.4546   645.174   665.855  2182.920   100  a 
 wbp2()   513.153   523.5715   568.0328   542.699   558.715  1814.073   100  a
```

result the same ( only names different) `all.equal(WBP(),wbp1())`